# How would I make the input border invisible?

Tags: html, css, input

I'm making a form, but I want the input field borders invisible. Is this possible? I've tried `<input type="text" style="display:none">` but that doesn't do anything. It just makes the whole input *invisible* and not input-able (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you your css file/codes just put the below line for achieve that objective

```
input { outline : none }
```

Comment: try that let me know about how it went :)

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: am happy for you, care to vote up then my friend

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint: Please do not disable outlines.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a border just put `border: none` but if you don't want a border when focusing the input put `outline: none`

*PS : As F. Müller said in the comments of the post, from the point of view of accessibility you should not disable the outlines.*

**Example :**

```css
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="myinput">
```

Comment: That also worked!! Thank you all!!

Comment: From an accessibility standpoint: Please do not disable outlines.

Comment: I have added your comment in the reply, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border: 0;` to remove the border of the input. You can also use `outline: 0;` to remove the outline on the focus.

Example:

```
input{
  border:0;
}

input:focus{
  outline:0;
}
```